# Skip over or exclude empty variable in field calculator expression

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to parse street addresses using the field calculator and return just the street name.  My expression works except for addresses where there is only a house number with no street name after it; the calculation throws an error when it gets to these bad records where the street name doesn't exist.  I would like to be able to skip over these bad addresses and just return the input string for them.  I have tried adding a second condition to my if statement, but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.  Essentially what I want to say is "if the house number is a digit and the street name is not blank, return the street name otherwise return the full input string"

```
def addressParser(inString):
    splitString = inString.split(' ',1)
    houseNumber = splitString[0]
    streetName = splitString[1]
    if houseNumber.isdigit() and if streetName != "":
        return streetName
    else:
        return inString

 addressParser( !FULLADDRESS! )
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Look into `try`/`except`? Addresses are _horrible_ to work with so I'm not sure that construct could ever be avoided.

Comment: OK thank you I will look into that.  I have a similar expression for house number that works well even if the field is blank b/c it uses "if houseNumber.isdigit return houseNumber, I tried something similar with "if streetName.isstring return streetName" but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Addresses generally have some freetext element in them, which is where the headache starts. Then you expand the system to somewhere like the Middle East where there is no formal address system (or anything at all beyond a description of the location). Try/except is a fundamental aspect of python that you'll need to learn even if you don't deal with such addresses.

Comment: thank you very much I definitely have alot to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can move your condition upward, before assigning `splitString[1]` to `streetName` so it does not raise an index out of range exception when the street name is not set,

```
def addressParser(inString):
    splitString = inString.split(' ',1)
    houseNumber = splitString[0]
    if houseNumber.isdigit() and len(splitString) >= 2:
        return splitString[1]
else:
    return inString
```

hope it helps